# php get the row from serialize data where condition is satisfied

Tags: php, mysql, serialization, deserialization

In mysql I have the table look like this

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `fl_details` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `country` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `language_pair` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ;
```

and the values inside table is like this. I have jut shown two entries. But there are more then 100 row present.

```
INSERT INTO `fl_details` (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `email`, `phone`, `country`, `language_pair`) VALUES
(1, 'asdf', 'erty', 'testuser@gmail.com', '12345678909', 'Sri Lanka', 'a:2:{s:6:"source";a:2:{i:0;a:1:{i:0;s:6:"Arabic";}i:1;a:1:{i:0;s:10:"Belarusian";}}s:6:"target";a:2:{i:0;a:2:{i:0;s:8:"Assamese";i:1;s:11:"Azerbaijani";}i:1;a:2:{i:0;s:10:"Belarusian";i:1;s:7:"Bengali";}}}'),
(2, 'asth', 'erui', 'testname@gmail.com', '12312356789', 'India', 'a:2:{s:6:"source";a:1:{i:0;a:1:{i:0;s:7:"English";}}s:6:"target";a:1:{i:0;s:5:"English";}}');
```

Here you can see I have entered the values for `language_pair` is in php [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) format. So both source and target language is stored in that column.
Now I want to fetch the total row whose target language is `Bengali`. So can someone kindly tell me how to do this? Any help and suggestions will be really appreacible. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this

```
SELECT * FROM fl_details WHERE language_pair REGEXP '.*"target";s:[0-9]+:"English".*'
```